# How can I maintain the list of names of the tibbles when using sapply function in R?

Tags: r

I have multiple functions that I need to run through sapply. However, the names aren't preserved when ran through the second sapply.

```
dmList <- sapply(unique(joint2$disease),
                  function(j) diseaseMutation(joint2, j),
                  simplify = FALSE)
```

The names of the tibbles are created to match the disease. I want to keep those names in the second sapply which is:

```
loopedList <- sapply(unique(dmList),
                     function(j) geneLoop2(j),
                     simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = T)
```

Instead of maintaining the names, the name of the tibbles within the list return to 1,2,3, etc..

Comment: Please show a smal reproducible example with expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames`:

```
loopedList <- setNames(sapply(unique(dmList),
                     function(j) geneLoop2(j),
                     simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = T), unique(dmList))
```